# Help w/ test class for when task updated lead status

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I am having some trouble with a test class for this code below. I am new to writing apex triggers and am lost on the text classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
trigger UpdateLeadswithTask on Task (after insert) {
    // set up lists you will need
    List<Lead> LeadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
    Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();

    // go through the list of tasks that were inserted
    for (Task t: Trigger.New)
    {
      // if they are related to a Lead, add the Lead id (whoID) and their values to a map
      if (t.WhoId  != null)
        {
            taskMap.put(t.WhoId, t);
        }
    }
    // if the map isnt empty
    if (taskMap.size() > 0)
    {
        // get all of the Leads related to the tasks
        LeadsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: taskMap.keySet()];
        // go through the list for each Lead
        for (Lead l: LeadsToUpdate)
        { if (l.Status =='Marketing Engaged')
            // set the new Lead status
            l.Status = 'Attempting';
         else
             System.debug('The Status of the Lead was not Working - Contacted');
        }

        // if the list of Leads isnt empty, update them
        if (LeadsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        {
            update LeadsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code is *entirely* too complex. Here's a trigger that does the same thing:

```
trigger UpdateLeadswithTask on Task (after insert) {
    Set<Id> whoIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.WhoId != null && record.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Lead.SObjectType) {
            whoIds.add(record.WhoId);
        }
    }
    if(!whoIds.isEmpty()) {
        Lead[] leadsToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :whoIds AND Status = 'Marketing Engaged'];
        for(Lead record: leadsToUpdate) {
            record.Status = 'Attempting';
        }
        update leadsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Now, for a unit test, you should use the standard Setup, Execute, Assert unit testing model:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    // Setup
    Lead[] leads = new Lead[] {
         new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test', Status='Marketing Engaged'),
         new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test', Status='Open')
    }
    insert leads;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[] {
        new Task(Subject='Test', WhoId=leads[0].Id, Status='Completed'),
        new Task(Subject='Test', WhoId=leads[1].Id, Status='Completed')
    };
    // Execute
    Test.startTest();
    insert tasks;
    Test.stopTest();
    // Assert
    System.assertEquals('Attempting',[SELECT Status FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leads[0].Id].Status);
    System.assertEquals(leads[1].Status,[SELECT Status FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leads[1].Id].Status);
}
```